# Pflanzen, einpflanzen, anpflanzen - Unterschied

Tags: prefix

Wo ist der Unterschied zwischen den drei Wörtern? Hängt es damit zusammen, was man pflanzt (z.B. einen Baum, Gemüse, Zimmerpflanzen) oder dem Ziel des Pflanzens? Ich habe auch gehört, dass man "eine Pflanze setzt". Ist das richtig?

Answer (score 2):

*einpflanzen* wird im Allgemeinen für Pflanzen verwendet, die in einem Topf oder in einem anderen "Behältnis" (das kann auch ein Beet sein) landen:

> Kakteen werden im Winter umgetopft und in einer speziellen Kakteenerde eingepflanzt.

*anpflanzen* wird verwendet, wenn man nicht speziell den Pflanzvorgang an sich oder gar eine einzelne Pflanze meint, sondern das, was der Engländer mit "to grow" meint - *anbauen* wäre ein passendes deutsches Synonym dafür:

> Die Gärtnerei Müller pflanzt Bohnen, Erbsen und andere Hülsenfrüchte nach biologisch-dynamischen Richtlinien an.

*pflanzen* ist der eigentliche Pflanzvorgang, in manchen Regionen (m.W. vor allem im Süden) wird für dieselbe Tätigkeit das Verb "setzen" synonym verwendet.

> Pflanzen Sie die Erdbeeren im Abstand von 30cm im Spätsommer oder Frühherbst.
>
> Die Salatpflanzen sollten in trockenen, nicht zu festen Boden gesetzt werden

Comment: Im Norden verwenden wir auch *setzen*. Pflanzen zu *pflanzen* ist das, was Schöngeister tun.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, wenn üblich es ist, aber "to plant in a specific place" ist nach Duden eine der Bedeutungen von "anpflanzen" (a). Die Bedeutung, die du gegeben hast, ist auch in Duden (c) .